# How to create a custom object using web sdk for quickblox?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, quickblox

I am working with the Web SDK of Quickblox creating a phonegap Android application. How do I create a custom object using JavaScript and a JSON array?

In my schema, I have the following fields:

1. msg
2. from
3. tom (js won't allow for)
4. avatar

I am creating the following query:

```
data = {
    "msg":msg,
    "from":from,
    "tom":to,
    "avatar":avatar`enter code here`
};
QB.data.create('chat', {data: data, type: 'POST'}, function(err, res){
        console.debug(data);
    });
```

I am getting only `null` in every field, why would this be?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
QB.data.create('chat', data, function(err, res){
  if (err) { 
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: I am not getting any errors. Its is a success where the id and created_at are correctly formed but rest is null.

Comment: You got in response `null` because you make the request incorrect.
Please, change next:
`QB.data.create('chat', {data: data, type: 'POST'}, callback);`
on only data:
`QB.data.create('chat', data, callback);`
without type: 'POST'. It will be automatically added in background into WebSDK.

Comment: I am requesting any response. After the initial POST, I am checking the values in the admin section and it is NULL.

Comment: Are you sure that you have changed rightly the format of your function - `QB.data.create('chat', data, callback);`? And more, the types of your fields from the Admin panel and the types of values you are sending from javascript are matched?